# how to handle null pointer in iteration with null key

Tags: java, collections

In a recent interview, question I faced was

> How can you handle null pointer when iterator encounters a null key
>   while iteration over a hashmap. assume my developer has inserted a
>   null key by mistake

My answer was: Just we need to check `null!=entry.getKey()`.
he was not satisfied and said before that how will you handle.

How should I answer that question. When I was back.

I tried this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(null, "null");
        map.put("null",null);
        map.put("test", "test");

        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next().getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
null
test
null
```

there is no exception. What was he trying to ask actually. or is that I am missing some concepts? Please guide me

Comment: "What was he trying to ask actually?" Well ... you should ask the interviewer. How can we know what he thought? There is no general way of handling null values in a collection or a map. It depends on the requirements. Maybe don't allow nulls beforehand?

Comment: Forgot to mention. he questioned like, assume my developer has inserted a null key..Edited question

Comment: You can use `HashTable`, then it will not allow user to add `null` key into a `HashTable`.

Comment: This is still very unclear. Is a null value in the map a valid value? If so, then handle it as a valid value. If it is not a valid value, then throw a NPE, thus reporting a programming error.

Comment: @Reno : May be he was expecting your answer :(

Comment: Also I read somewhere better implementation other than HashTable is ConcurrentHashMap. May be I should have answered him developer must use concurrent hashmap. I was confused cause he said developer inserted null value. Means he is already using haspmap.

Comment: @Aadam Exactly, some interviewer always wants he want you to say, not a way to solve the question.

Comment: Question is very unclear: *"How can you handle null"* and *"assume my developer has inserted a null key by mistake"*. What makes it a mistake? Nothing is that question says that null keys are not allowed, so "how to handle" and "insert by mistake" is impossible to answer, other than how you did: Check for it and react accordingly, whatever "accordingly" means.

Comment: @Aadam If he mentioned 'HashMap' in question, you cannot use Hashtable :) You recollect the question once again ? He might have some answer in mind and asked a question to support it ;-)

Comment: And if his developer has made a mistake, it's his mistake of inserting null value on a HashMap and we can only do a null check before operation if the null key operation was allowed. And again giving the Hashtable can't be a solution coz it depends on requirement of whether synchronization is req etc

Comment: @Karthik. I remember clearly that he first asked does hashmap allow null keys, I said yes only one, then he fired this question. thats the reason I got confused and dint say developer should use concurrenthashmap. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
map.remove(null)
```

From JavaDocs:

> Returns the value to which this map previously associated the key, or null if the map contained no mapping for the key.
>
> If this map permits null values, then a return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contained no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly mapped the key to null.
>
> The map will not contain a mapping for the specified key once the call returns.

Call it before iteration, and it will remove explicit null keys

Answer (score -2):

I guess the key point that he want to test by this question is What happend when called the method `next()` on the object `Iterator`.

He maybe want to know whether or not you will programming like the following way when you want to iterate a map:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Iterator iter = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      if (null != iter.next().key()) {
         System.out.println(iter.next());
      }
}
```

If you programming like above example, the `next` method will called twice, and you will not get the correct object that you really want to check. Instead, you should write code like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Iterator iter = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      // Key point: define a refreence point to the object returned by the
      // method `next()`
      Entry entry = iter.next();
      if (null != entry.key()) {
         System.out.println(entry);
      }
}
```

Comment: Since the answer OP gave was `null!=entry.getKey()`, the fallacy of calling `next()` twice is already covered, so that is not why interviewer was not satisfied.